# exporting large figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, dendrogram

I am trying to output an image of a [dendrogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) made using scipy. When I export an image the text is totally unreadable as I have 3000+ leaf nodes. Any idea how to make this thing manageable?

example of my code right now

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import ward, dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lmat = ward(dist)

ax = dendrogram(lmat, orientation="right", labels=names)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('dendrogram.png')
```

If I manually set a very large image size

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 200))
```

I get errors like this

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  53 (X_CreatePixmap)
Serial number of failed request:  298
Current serial number in output stream:  300
```

I guess one solution is to manually zoom in on sections of it using the GUI and save/join those images, but I would really prefer to not do something like that!

Comment: have you tried a vector graphics format? Not sure if that'll work, though.

Comment: You might want to reconsider whether a ginormous dendrogram is really the best way to represent your data. I don't see a great deal of point in trying to represent all 3000+ leaf nodes - even if you can generate the figure it would be very hard for anyone to interpret, let alone getting it to look nice on screen or in print. At the very least it would probably make more sense to truncate it (see the `truncate_mode` parameter).

Comment: @cel A vector output does seem to solve the memory problem, though not my visualization issue

Comment: @ali_m I am aware that it is maybe not the most practical of outputs, but I was planning to use some javascript,etc to display a continuous scrolling of the leaves

Comment: @user1984528, I fully agree with ali_m here. You surely can create such kind of plot, but it will probably not possible to extract any relevant information from it.

Comment: You might consider using something like [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), which is designed for visualising large graphs and can support interactive zooming and scrolling. [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/) and [pygraphviz](https://pygraphviz.github.io/) provide some Python bindings.

Comment: @ali_m thanks for the info, will check out GraphViz

Comment: We tend to refer to graphs like this as [ridiculograms](http://aidcomplexity.blogs.casa.ucl.ac.uk/2014/06/05/untangling-the-ridiculogram/) :-)

Comment: Did you try to set the figure size? It works the following way: `fig.set_size_inches((16, 12))`.

Comment: @jkalden yes, I tried setting the size, but matplotlib really does like to make a figure of the size I want. I think the short answer is that what I want to do is so far from the normal use case for matplotlib that I am better off using GraphViz,etc as others have suggested

Comment: People say that *can create such plot*, but how? We fully agree that it could not be the best option, but if it is possible, how to do?